Difference between grade averages of different graders
I am a teacher and we now had our end-of-semester exam in which $N$ students participated.
I have $k$ graders each graded a certain amount of exams $N_i$, so $\sum_{i=1}^kN_i=N$.
When I check the results, naturally there is a difference between the averages and distribution of grades between every grader.
What I want to know is, what is a 'reasonable' variance between the averages.
If I take a random partition of the grades, what will be the mean variance or mean max difference between to averages.
other than a direct answer, I will be happy for any theory in probability or statistics that is relevant to this problem.
Edit: All the graders got a very detailed grading instructions, and we may assume the papers where divided randomly between them.
By 'reasonable' variance I mean variance that is not implied by one or more graders who deviated from the instructions.
For example, if I had only two graders and I see that on one group there are 51% grades of '0' and 49% grades of '1' and on the other group the other way around, then I will not suspect any wrong-doing by the graders. But if one grader gave only '0' grades and the other only '1's, although it is possible, it is highly unlikely both graders had the same standards while grading the exams.

When you say "reasonable variance", do you mean "under the assumption that all graders grade in exactly the same way, what kind of variance between the graders is reasonable to see due only to the fact that they grade randomly assigned papers"? Or do you mean "since no two humans are the same, what kind of variance is reasonable to see due to the fact that different graders grade differently"?

Sounds like a job for ANOVA.

As a simplified model,  you might imagine that each paper had a grade printed on it,  and all the graders just reported that value.  Of course,  it would still be true that each grader would get a different variance, just by sampling error.  That sort of Standard Error is unavoidable, and you would then be interested in  seeing if the observed variances were out of line with that.

Thank you for your comments. See the edit, I tried to explain better what I meant.
